# Can't infer object type from object property

Tags: typescript

In this code:

```
type Type1 = { value: string; test: number };
type Type2 = { value: [string]; test: boolean };
type MyType = Type1 | Type2;
let test = (x: MyType) => {
  if (typeof x.value === "string") {
    console.log(x.value, typeof x.test);
    return;
  }
};
```

if you hover over `x.test` it says the type is `number | boolean`.
Why can't it deduce that it is of type `number` actually? Doesn't the `if` statement guarantee that?

Comment: Only `x.value` is narrowed. To narrow `x`, you should use a type predicate, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRXEQm).

Comment: @caTS Fine but my question was *why* TS can't infer the object type in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates). This specific use case is actually tracked in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) yet to be resolved. TypeScript as of now only knows that the *child* object is that certain type, but it doesn't bother to infer the parent object:

```
type Type1 = { value: string; test: number };
type Type2 = { value: [string]; test: boolean };
type MyType = Type1 | Type2;

function isType1(x: MyType): x is Type1 {
  return typeof x.value === "string";
}

let test = (x: MyType) => {
  if (isType1(x)) {
    console.log(x.value, typeof x.test);
    return;
  }
};

test({ value: "hi", test: 2 })
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oG8oDcCGAbArhAFxQDOwATgJYB2A5gNxTATkk34C2ARhBVAF8GAKFCRY8AEwp0WPIRIBtctXoBdJizZRuAe124I2GoJFjoAWRBxxqG4igAfCZEkjhAM3w0AxsCq6JlSk9ggAFAAeJFb2AJQkEVDBLg5owlBQFBDA%20BQm5roeUBEAdDgE0MhVUABEKrR0NSICwsKGwMysHaiR0dbwsSgAfOjpSUVhwaGRsYNpGRk%20gaQGECW4unSRZfIQADTM8IXFJVrAsSILmdm5NJeCwkKtZ2EY5Qq1ABZUNQdnJNIBLEgA)

Comment: Hm elsewhere I encountered such explanation about this: "Since members of a union might overlap, TS needs a more reliable way to know when we're in one case of union type vs another". Does this make sense to you? Didn't get what they mean.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Your example doesn't have a union that has overlapping membes, but for example, if they both had another property with the same type, then they would be overlapping, which means TS can't differentiate between them.

Comment: @caTS I see thanks, strangely that explanation was used on an example similar to mine. But thanks.